# How can I terminate user input without using zero?

Tags: java, arrays

Basically I'm trying to make an method that would return an array so that I can use this list later down the line, only problem is I cant find a way to terminate user input other than using 0. I've tried to take in user input using a string then parsing it into an int but that only results in an error when a non-number character is used.

```
public static double[] input()
{
    double[] arr = new double[100];
    //int count = 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.print("Insert a number or Zero to stop: ");
        double input = scan.nextDouble();
        arr[i] = input;

        if(input == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        count++;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Introducing: [`hasNextDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextDouble()) which will return `true` until your user presses Ctrl+D.

Comment: Did you try Googling for ___java scanner terminate input___ ? I found this: [Scanner input - end of input stream indicator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20722857/scanner-input-end-of-input-stream-indicator) Does it help? There are lots more results if it doesn't.

Comment: @MarcLeBihan that's not what upvotes are for, One upvote (+10 rep) is completely disproportionate compared to a downvote (-1 rep). A downvote *may* not have been warranted here, but you should upvote questions that deserve an upvote, not question that received *one*  downvote.

Comment: @MarcLeBihan Please read [this meta answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252740/11573842). Downvoting is completely subjective and one can't hold the downvoter/s answerable to their downvote/s.

Comment: @naoh You certainly don't have to settle for requiring entry of a zero to signal end-of-input.  What would you prefer to do instead?

Comment: @KevinAnderson Anything other than a number. I've tried using a string and parseInt so that when its a number, it will go in the array, but if its the word "stop" then it would break and return the array. This results in a NumberFormatException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that instead of the condition `for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)` you could simply ask the user how many digits he/she wishes to enter and then pass that value to the for loop to execute lie `for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)` where length is the user desired size of array.

If you do not want to ask the user then do this accept the numbers as single characters instead of a string then before parsing it into int just check if the entered character is an escape sequence(\n or \r) `arr[index]='\n' or'\r'` then you can terminate the input process.

Note: this process is only for integer input if the user enters a character it accepts it just make sure that the entered character is a number.

I suggest you put the print statement out of the for loop as it will be repeated as long as the for loop runs, it is not nice to have those instructions displayed again and again.